# Drop down not centering relative to parent

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to center my drop down `<ul class="second-level">` list. The parent `<li>` has`position: relative;` and the child `<ul>` has `position: absolute;`, but it's still not centered.

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ut0veyhc/1/)

Comment: I think it has something to do with adding a width to the drop down menu (which is what I want to do). Whenever I add a width the menu goes off to one side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this in your code

```
 <style>
        /** Desktop **/
header #desktop-nav {
    padding: 0 0 20px;
}
header #desktop-nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 175px;
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
header #desktop-nav ul li:first-child {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 13px;
    width: 40px;
    left: -20px;
}


  header #desktop-nav ul li ul.second-level {
        background: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 36px;
    left: -4em;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
header #desktop-nav ul li ul.second-level .arrow-container {
    color: #4c4c4c;
    position: relative;
    top: 6px;
}
header #desktop-nav ul li ul.second-level li {
    padding: 12px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #67676b;
    background: #4c4c4c;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    width: 240px;
}
header #desktop-nav ul li ul.second-level li:last-child {
    border-bottom: 0 solid transparent !important;
}
header #desktop-nav ul li ul.second-level li a {
    display: block;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #eaeaea;
    border-bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;

}
header #desktop-nav ul li ul.second-level li a > img {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
}
header #desktop-nav ul li ul.second-level li:hover {
    background: #363636;
}
header #desktop-nav ul li ul.second-level li .up-arrow {
    color: #4c4c4c;
    cursor: default;
    font-size: 14px;
    left: 48%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -11px;
}
header #desktop-nav ul li.active a {
    color: #c40009;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #c40009;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
header #desktop-nav ul li:hover > .second-level {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}
header #desktop-nav ul li:hover > a {
    color: #c40009;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #c40009;
    color: #c40009;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}
header #desktop-nav ul li:hover > a.stickyLogo {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
header #desktop-nav a {
    -webkit-transition: color 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: color 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: color 0.4s;
    transition: color 0.4s;
}

    </style>
```

Comment: Updated the Fiddle with your code, still not working - https://jsfiddle.net/ut0veyhc/2/

Comment: use this edited answer which has the full stylesheet and copy paste it in place of the original styles

Comment: Hmm, I replaced it all and it's still not centered. I want the drop down box to appear in the middle of the parent LI

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with a `transform:translateX();` rule.

See updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ut0veyhc/4/

Here's the css:

```
.second-level {
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-25%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-25%);
  transform: translateX(-25%);
}
```

*EDIT*

Sorry, I forgot to add the css3 prefixes - I've updated the link with the new fiddle.